# What's the best way to sort function inputs based on type in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function with several inputs, which I would like to be optional in calling the function. Each input is of a different type, such as string, array, or number. With code like this:

```
function doStuff(str, arr, num){
    if typeof(str) != 'undefined' { $('#stringDiv').text(str)}

    if typeof(arr) != 'undefined' {
        for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
            $('<li>').text(arr[i]).appendTo('#arrayUl')
        }
    }

    if typeof(num) != 'undefined' { $('#numberDiv').text(num)}
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    doStuff("i'm a string", [1,2,3,4,5], 7)
})
```

I can account for the fact that my arguments might be optional, but not for the fact that, if I am missing `arr`, then my numeric argument (`num`) will come second, not third.

To get around this, I can also dump my inputs into an array, and then sort through the array and look for this of each type, like I do in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bGTva/4/) This seems sloppy, and, based on the number of libraries that I've seen that do this in their functions, it seems like there's probably a better way. Is there a better way to do this? Or is looping through arguments and hunting for types my best bet?

Comment: I would consider using an options object for this. Then all your parameters would be explicitly defined.

Comment: Some think that the right way to order formal parameters is to put the most "stable" parameters first. That lets you make better use of `.bind()` to create variations on the basic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leave off all parameters and use the `arguments` list to see what was passed.

But, a better approach would be to create an object like this:

```
{
    str: "i'm a string",
    arr: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    num: 3.14
}
```

And then inspect the object for those keys:

```
function doStuff(args):
    if ('str' in args) {
        $('#stringDiv').text(args.str);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object

```
function doStuff(args) {
    // Do something with args.num
    if (typeof args.num !== "undefined") { ... }
    // Same for arr and str
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I don't want to explicitly define an object each time I call my code? I'd really like something like **kwargs from python, but I don't think that exists.

Comment: The "arguments" variable that is available in every function might do what you want, then, but it will just give you an array of all the passed arguments, and will not name them. So you still need to figure out what is what by their type.

Comment: If `args.num` evaluates to false, such as when it is `0`, it will not run as expected.

Comment: It was just for illustration purposes, but now that you told everybody, I can't just leave it like that ;-) Updated!

Answer (score 0):

> Or is looping through arguments and hunting for types my best bet?

Yes, that is perfectly fine. No need to sort them. Also, you can use the array-like [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) so you don't have to build that `args` array manually from a fixed amount of parameters.

```
function doStuff() {
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        var a = arguments[i];
        if (typeof a == 'string')
            $('#stringDiv').text(str);
        else if (Array.isArray(a)) // or check typeof a == 'object'
            for(var j=0; j < a.length; j++)
                $('<li>').text(a[j]).appendTo('#arrayUl');
        else if (typeof a == 'number')
            $('#numberDiv').text(num);
    }
}
```